# Включение кириллицы в buildroot

Tags: linux, arm

Попытка включения кириллицы оказалась без успешной.

Доказательство:

```
# echo "Это образец текста" > файл.txt
# ls
 rc.local  ''$'\364\340\351\353''.txt получил '\364\340\351\353' вместо 'файл'
```

Что сделал:

```
В Buildroot:
make menuconfig

Toolchain --->
Enable toolchain locale/i18n

System configuration ---> 
(C en_US) Locales to keep
(ru_RU.UTF-8) Generate locale data
[*] Enable Native Language Support (NLS)

Filesystem and flash utilities --->
[*] ntfs-3g

Target packages --->
Hardware handling --->
[*] kbd

Target packages --->
System tools --->
[*] coreutils

В ядре:
File systems --->
-*- Native language support --->
<*> Codepage 866 (Cyrillic/Russian)
<*> Windows CP1251 (Bulgarian, Belarusian)
<*> NLS UTF-8
<*>ASCII (United States)
<*>   NLS KOI8-R (Russian)

Все перепроверил еще на раз и пересобрал buildroot.

В profile прописал export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 

Кто знает, в чем ошибка?
```

Comment: Скорее всего, в локали. Что говорит команда locale?

Comment: Команда locale не работает. #  locale
-sh: locale: not found

Comment: а какая консоль и  тип терминала?

Comment: ARM,  IMX287-evk

Comment: А содержимое файла корректно отображается?

Comment: Нет не верно. Тут как понимаю беда с coreutils. Кодировка между консолью и таргетом неверная. Сама кириллица во фреймбуфере работает. Тут именно консоль.

Comment: uClibc или Glibc? Поддержка wchar включена? Пакет типа `libiconv` стоит?

Comment: glibc. Поддержка wchar включена в Toolchain. libiconv не стоит. У меня его в buildroot нет, наверное нужно еще что-то включить сначала.